# Сохранение табоицы в localStorage

Tags: javascript, table

Мне нужно сохранить данные неупорядоченной таблицы в localStorage и потом воссоздать ее при перезагрузке страницы. Самый простой способ, который я вижу - сохранять сам объект таблицы table/tbody. Но насколько это "правильное" решение? Разве мы вместе с объектом не "тащим" кучу ненужных нам данных и свойств в localStorage?

Будет ли правильным сделать подобное через сохранение данных ячеек в двумерный неупорядоченный массив, который обновляется и сохраняется в localStorage Каждый раз, когда в какую-нибудь ячейку новое значение записывается? Примерно такой объект с массивом:

```
tableData = {
    columns: 0,
    rows: 0,
    data: [*тут индексы - номер ряда. Индексы вложенного массива - номер ячейки*]
}
```

Comment: А как вы планируете сохранять объект таблицы в localStorage? Там ведь можно хранить только строки, а объекты DOM без потерь не сериализируются в строки (например, через JSON). Можно использовать ваш второй вариант или хранить там HTML.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "хранить там HTML"? Я еще только учусь. Спасибо за комментарий

Comment: Одно из этих свойств элемента таблицы: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML или https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: И какой способ лучше всего подходит? Хранить сразу текст HTML или хранить данные в неупорядоченном двумерном массиве?

Comment: Трудно сказать) Хранение массива (в JSON) может занимать меньше места, но превращение таблицы в массив и массив в таблицу может занимать дополнительное время. Можете потестировать, и если время и место не критичны, делайте, как вам удобнее будет писать код, например.

Comment: Благодарю за совет)

Comment: А есть ли способ при сохранении через HTML сохранить также и привязанные слушатели событий? Например слушатель onclick события?

Comment: К сожалению, нет, если этот слушатель не закодирован в атрибуте элемента. Придётся каждый раз при пересоздании таблицы заново привязывать слушатели. Но вы можете использовать делегирование событий, тогда не придётся: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation